# How do I make embedded website's fullscreen to occupy iframe only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

How do I make an embedded website's "fullscreen" open fullscreen inside its own iFrame instead of "literal" fullscreen?

```
<body>
<iframe><!--youtube in fullscreen here--></iframe>

<!--still displaying normal website(with fullscreen iframe)-->

<body>
```

Ask if you need clarification.(It's hard to describe) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:fixed` as shown in below code.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
iframe{
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: I need to have more than one video going at once, though. I need to have 4 videos all fullscreen in their respective iframes @Maddy

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the embedded youtube feature, since how i'm reading this, you just want the video, not the website

[Link for Tutorial](http://mobile.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3480061/How-To-Add-a-YouTube-Video-to-Your-Web-Site.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following inline style on your iframe HTML tag.

Basically you can use:

`position:fixed` to position your iframe relativelly to your viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

`width:100%; height:100%` Set the size of your iframe as your viewport (this allows you to create the full screen effect).

---

```
<iframe src="http://your-iframe-here.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
</iframe>
```